# How to get parameter from URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url

I passed a parameter through an URL using javascript. Here's the code:

```js
<script> 
window.onload = function() {
// Creating a cookie after the document is ready 
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";")
    var cookiePair = cookies[0].split("=");
    var cookie_user=cookiePair[1]; // remove ending parenthesis here 

 window.location.replace("http://192.168.206.1/foodblog/?page=http://192.168.206.1/test/ChangeInfo.php&username="+cookie_user);
};
</script>
```

The page that received the parameter is called ChangeInfo
This is what I see in the URL when I get to the ChangeInfo page:
http://192.168.206.1/foodblog/?page=http://192.168.206.1/test/ChangeInfo.php&username=nitzan

When I'm trying to get the parameter username from the URL, I get this error:
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\ChangeInfo.php on line 5

The way I'm trying to get this parameter is to use $_GET like that: $username = $_GET['username'];

Does anyone know why this makes me a problem? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should put the **PHP** code for solving your question , not javascript's . and the error is for that there is no index **5** in array username.

Comment: my php code in the ChangeInfo page is :   $username = $_GET['username'];   I wanted to get the value of username parameter from the URL i created on the javascript part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I just solve the problem

I deleted the Page parameter from the URL I created in javascript part.
this is the updated Javascript part:

```js
<script> 
window.onload = function() {
// Creating a cookie after the document is ready 
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";")
    var cookiePair = cookies[0].split("=");
    var cookie_user=cookiePair[1]; // remove ending parenthesis here 

 window.location.replace("http://192.168.206.1/test/ChangeInfo.php?username="+cookie_user);
};
</script>
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the javascript part, needing to focus on PHP.

You are on this page:
http://192.168.206.1/foodblog/?page=http://192.168.206.1/test/ChangeInfo.php&username=nitzan

And when you use $_GET['username'] you get the error, that it is not assigned.
It seems that your $_GET is not working at all, probably Apache settings.

Also, it is safer to get GET parameters with isset first.

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username']] {
  $username = $_GET['username'];
}
else {
  $username = '';
}
```

Then you can compare, if username is set or not in your php code:

```
if($username) {
  //Do something
}
```

Final thought. Is your first parameter page=http://192.168.206.1/test/ChangeInfo.php working? Can you get it through $_GET?

The problem seems to be just in the way you set and get the url parameter though $_GET. If you use some framework, it might be disabled to use $_GET directly and for example in Symfony you need to use:

```
$request->get('username');
```

Comment: I think you haven't understood OPs question fully. Their problem is that they don't receive the value of `$_GET['username']`

Comment: no the $_GET for page parameter is not working either . maybe the problem is the way I created the URL in the javascript part?